# iOS Swift CLLocationManager not getting exact location

Tags: ios, swift2, location, cllocationmanager

I am facing some issue with my iOS app.My code for getting user's current location works fine in most of the cases but sometimes it shows current location to be very very far away from current location , even outside country.

Code in my viewDidLoad method :

```
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

function for handling location change

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    Swift.print(locations[0].coordinate.longitude)
    Swift.print(locations[0].coordinate.latitude)
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Please guide me what else to do in order to get the user's location correctly everytime. I am using Swift 2.

Comment: It is a bad idea to call `stopUpdatingLocation` straight away. The first location could be inaccurate. Check the `horizontalAccuracy` property

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code, work with background mode and foreground mode able to fetch location.

### Swift 2.2

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
}
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

I hope this will help you.You need to avoid kCLLocationAccuracyBest because it will drain device battery quickly. so set particular distance filter then it will good for you app.